# Copy stored procedure from one database to another using T-sql

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic, copy

I'm using sql server

I want to copy a stored procedure from one database to another using T-sql,
but my stored procedure contains dynamic sql.

I get the definition from `sys.sql_modules` and execute it using this code

```
exec sp_executesql @sp_definition
```

but it gives me error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 23 Incorrect syntax near ' + @tblName + '

Example of my stored procedure

```
CREATE Procedure insertRow
(
    @tblName nvarchar(250), 
    @value  nvarchar(250)
)
AS
    DECLARE @script nvarchar(1000)
    SET @script='INSERT INTO '+@tblName +' VALUES('+@value+')'
    exec @script
```

How can i escape the quotes to execute it succesfully

Comment: could u Give us an example ??

Comment: *but it gives me errors* is not very clear. Try to print out the content of `@sp_definition` and try to execute this directly. Do you get the same errors? Might be connected to *internal quotes* due to your dynamic SQL...

Comment: Since it gives you errors, you should give us errors--kind of helps

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 23
Incorrect syntax near ' + @tblName + '

Comment: The error is because your didn't spell VALUES correctly. Thankfully this failed or you might have actually used this in your system. This stored procedure is wide open to sql injection attack. This is example of trying to create the "one procedure to rule them all". Don't do this to yourself. Create an insert procedure for all your tables and avoid dynamic sql where you directly execute input values like this. My friend bobby tables loves this kind of thing. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: this is example but not my real code , here i want to show example of stored procedure that uses dynamic sql

Comment: Try adding a print command tight after the SET command something like     PRINT @Script. then it ill show you what the query looks like. You are gonna have to just play around with quote marks until you get it right, At least this way it shows you what it sees,

Comment: the syntax of this procedure is correct , the error occurs when i try to copy this stored procedure to another database using t-sql : my process is :1- select sp(named inserRow) definition from database1 and execute it using exec in database2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to escape quotes properly and using ''' instead of only one quote